# Powershell script help to merge data

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

Sorry, I'm not very good with powershell can anyone offer a solution please? There's a server with 20,000 folders each folder is a job number and inside each folder is many sub folders with .msg files.  I want to copy all *.msg files into a single folder in another directory with the job number as the folder name.  SoI get 20,000 new folders.

Complicated to explain but it's too do with a 3rd party app and the devs want $20,000 to do it using the app but it can be done in the backend I'm sure.

I've put together this script and it gets all the msg files but it dumps them into the root:

```
$dir = 'C:\Users\damia\OneDrive\Desktop\b'

$folder     = (Get-Item $dir) 
$folderName = $folder.Name
$folderPath = $folder.FullName

Get-ChildItem $dir -Recurse |
    Select-Object Name, FullName,
        @{n='FolderName';e={$folderName}},
        @{n='Folder';e={$folderPath}} |

         Export-Csv 'C:\Users\damia\OneDrive\Desktop\b\output.csv' -Encoding UTF8 -NoType


# Set the source and destination paths (No trailing slash)
$source = "C:\Users\damia\OneDrive\Desktop\b"
$dest = "C:\Users\damia\OneDrive\Desktop\a"

# Get a list of all files recursively
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $source -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PsIsContainer -eq $false -and $_.extension -eq ".msg" } 

# Process each file
$files | ForEach-Object {
    # Basename is filename w/o ext
    $baseName = $_.BaseName
    $ext = $_.Extension
    # Build initial new file path
    $newName = "$dest\$Name\$($_.Name)"

    # Check for duplicate file
    If (Test-Path $newName) {
        $i = 0
        # While the file exists, increment the number that will be appended
        #While (Test-Path $newName) {
       #     $i++
        #    $newName = "$dest\$baseName($i)$ext"
     #   }
    } 
    # If the file is not a duplicate, write the (placeholder) file.
    Else {
        New-Item -ItemType File -Path $newName -Force
    }

    # Copy the file contents to the destination
     Copy-Item $_.FullName -Destination $newName -Force
}
```

Comment: Line 28, `$Name` is not anything; should it be `$($_.FolderName)` maybe?

Comment: Thanks.  I tried your suggestion and it puts it into a folder name but it's the parent folder.